# How do I remove `cannot find name` for the SpeechRecognition API in Typescript, aka what does 'Now provided by --lib dom' mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, speech-recognition, yarn-v2

```
recognition: SpeechRecognition | undefined;
this.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition(); 
this.recognition.onresult = (event: SpeechRecognitionEvent) => {});
```

Each throw a `cannot find name` warning for each of `SpeechRecognition`, `webkitSpeechRecognition`, and `SpeechRecognitionEvent`

I tried `yarn -D add @types/webspeechapi` but it produced an error, and indeed it is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webspeechapi) with the message `Now provided by --lib dom`. Unfortunately, I have no idea what this means!

Comment: I think it got moved to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dom-speech-recognition

Answer (score 1):

try this instead `npm install --save @types/dom-speech-recognition` worked for me